# Updating a Rails Bundle Package

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I want to make a Rails Bundle Package for a client. I am using Rails 3.0.3 and Ruby 1.9.2. What is the process if I need to update the bundle package with new gem versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to update the gems used in a rails project? My guess is that you update the versions in the GemFile

```
gem 'name', 'version'
```

and then run bundle install.. This will install all the appropriate versions.

Comment: You should try to avoid adding the version as much as possible. Let bundler handle it. If you must, then do it in a loose way, as described here, http://ryanbigg.com/2011/01/why-you-should-run-bundle-update/, by Ryan Bigg.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update to a specific version, use @Ferdy's answer, but if you just want to update to the most recent version run:

```
bundle update gem_name
```

This will update your gem to the latest version, and also update all of its dependencies. It will also update your Gemfile.lock file so that you can commit it to source code. Other systems will now just need to run:

```
bundle install
```

to get the update.